# AngularJS - Trigger when radio button is selected

Tags: angularjs

I searched and tried many ng-xxxx kind of options but couldn't find the one..
I just want to call some function in the controller when radio button is selected.

So it might be similar to following..(Of course, below code is not working)

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="one" ng-click="checkStuff()"/>
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 239):

There are at least 2 different methods of invoking functions on radio button selection:

1) Using `ng-change` directive:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
```

and then, in a controller:

```
$scope.newValue = function(value) {
     console.log(value);
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPcSe/5/

2) Watching the model for changes. This doesn't require anything special on the input level:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo">
```

but in a controller one would have:

```
$scope.$watch('value', function(value) {
       console.log(value);
 });
```

And the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vDTRp/2/

Knowing more about your the use case would help to propose an adequate solution.

Comment: I'm using AngularJS Bootstrap bindings. Watch doesn't work, but the ng-change handler does.

Comment: Is there a way to use a single ng-change directive for the radio group?

Comment: The word `value` is making it quite confusing.

Comment: @jEremyB .. I don't know about the single `ng-change` specifically ... but you can avoid multiple event-handlers (such as having an `ng-change=...` on every `input`) by using method 2: every input requires an `ng-model` and then you have a single `watch` listening for the change ...

Comment: why not ng-click?

Comment: FYI - The `value` parameter in the ng-change isn't automatically set to anything. Otherwise, helpful solution.

Comment: what about a radio button group? how do I do it when any from the group is selected?

Answer (score 19):

Should use ngChange instead of ngClick if trigger source is not from click.

Is the below what you want ? what exactly doesn't work in your case ?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value = "none" ;
    $scope.isChecked = false;
    $scope.checkStuff = function () {
        $scope.isChecked = !$scope.isChecked;
    }
}


<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="one" ng-change="checkStuff()" />
    <span> {{value}} isCheck:{{isChecked}} </span>
</div>
```

Comment: That only works for clicks. What if the uses sets a radio button using the keyboard?

Answer (score 8):

In newer versions of angular (I'm using 1.3) you can basically set the model and the value and the double binding do all the work this example works like a charm:

```js
angular.module('radioExample', []).controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.color = {
    name: 'blue'
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body ng-app="radioExample">
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red">  Red <br/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="green"> Green <br/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue"> Blue <br/>
  <tt>color = {{color.name}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

For dynamic values!

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="(k, v) in tiposAcesso">
    <label class="control-label">
        <input type="radio" name="tipoAcesso" ng-model="userLogin.tipoAcesso" value="{{k}}" ng-change="changeTipoAcesso(k)" />              
        <span ng-bind="v"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.changeTipoAcesso = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: Edit: It worked for me when use ng-click instead of ng-change. Also, not using ng-model here.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is using `Object.defineProperty` to set `value`as a getter setter property in the controller scope, then each change on the value property will trigger a function specified in the setter:

The HTML file:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="one"/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="two"/>
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="three"/>
```

The javascript file:

```
var _value = null;
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'value', {
  get: function () {
    return _value;
  },         
  set: function (value) {
    _value = value;
    someFunction();
  }
});
```

see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tf27iTBfyeJighNT8hMp?p=preview) for the implementation

Answer (score 2):

i prefer to use ng-value with ng-if, 
[ng-value] will handle trigger changes

```
<input type="radio"  name="isStudent" ng-model="isStudent" ng-value="true" />

//to show and hide input by removing it from the DOM, that's make me secure from malicious data

<input type="text" ng-if="isStudent"  name="textForStudent" ng-model="job">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
   <label data-ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]"><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="$parent.radioValue" value="{{i}}"/>{{i}}</label>
   <div>currently selected: {{radioValue}}</div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```