# AngularJS : ng-repeat on radio button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi Am trying to achieve an html where when you click a radio button, I want to update my Obj.

so when I click save button I will send my Obj to api to save the data.

My problem is I am lost on how to make a radio button that will update my obj?

is this posible.?

```
 scope.Obj =   [
      {
        "condition": "Question1",
        "status": ""
      },
      {
        "condition": "Question2",
        "status": ""
      },
      {
        "condition": "Question3",
        "status": ""
      }
     ]
```

HTML OUTPUT

```
Question                                    Status (Radio Button)

Question1                                      yes[]    no[]
Question2                                      yes[]    no[]
Question3                                      yes[]    no[]

                                                 [ Save ]
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077320/angularjs-trigger-when-radio-button-is-selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just display your object you will see that it is bound to the values.

```
<div ng-repeat="o in obj">
      Yes <input type="radio" ng-model="o.status" value="yes" />
      No <input type="radio" ng-model="o.status" value="no"  /> 
...

{{obj}}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/ZPcSe/504/)