# Trouble setting event handler on bootstrap-switch element with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events, bootstrap-select

The context is I have a radio button in my angular application that triggers a drop-down menu to appear. I'm attempting to attach an event listener that will fire off an AJAX request to a server and populate the drop-down list with the response. I'm using angular-bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select for the switch.

My initial approach was to simply add an ng-click directive to the div surrounding the button, which works, but the request is only sent if the user clicks on the white part of the button:

Image of button:

[image: http://imgur.com/YBOT6x1]

However the click doesn't register if the user clicks the grey part where it reads "All". I also tried wrapping the div in an anchor and attaching the ng-click to that but that did not work either.

I also tried to use the method in the documentation:
[bootstrap-switch-event](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/events.html)

My code:

```
    $('input[id="mySwitch"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    console.log('event triggered');
    if ( !itemsCalled ) {
        myService.items.get().$promise.then(function(response) {
            $scope.itemList = response.items;
        });
        itemsCalled = true;
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<input bs-switch id="mySwitch" ng-model="item" type="radio" switch-on-text="All" switch-off-text="Custom" switch-on-color="grey" switch-off-color="blue" switch-animate="true" switch-size="small" ng-value="'All'" ng-true-value="'All'" ng-false-value="'Custom'">
```

And a bunch of variations of this with no success. I'm pretty new to angular so I'm not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way or not.

Comment: Aquí está la solución: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077320/angularjs-trigger-when-radio-button-is-selected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the Ajax call when the switch change from `"Custom"` to `"All"` :

```js
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('item', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(newValue === "All") {
           // Ajax call
          alert("ajax");
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">

<input ng-model="item" type="radio" ng-value="'All'" ng-true-value="'All'" ng-false-value="'Custom'">
  
<button ng-click="item = 'Custom'">Reset</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking to make the call whenever the switch is pressed, from any part of the switch.