# Change span class on click angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, class, toggleclass

Good day! I have a span in my code. The class contains image that is displayed via span. Once the user clicked the image, its class should change and when another span is clicked, it should go back to the original class

```
 <span alt="Mode1" ng-class="{'mode': isActive}" ng-click="activeButton()"  ></span></span>
```

on my controller

```
  $scope.isActive = false;
  $scope.activeButton = function() {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  }
```

It is already working but my problem is on the load there is nothing displayed and it only shows when I click it. Im using angularjs btw

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing is displayed* There is only one span and if it is not there where do you click. Explain your problem in detail and post the relevant code in the post.

Comment: Where is the class that you have to show on load? If `mode` class is shown on `ng-click`?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya the span shows images when it is click the colored image counterpart should be shown but my code above displays nothing only after I clicked it, the colored counterpart is shown

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat, I think thats my problem because on load, the class that is supposed to be shown is none, How will I put that?

Comment: ng-class="{'mode': isActive,'in-active-class':!isActive}"

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury, I tried it but the problem is still the same the class that is supposed to be shown on load is not displayed but when I click, the changed class is shown

Comment: @DrJones, I can't make it work on plunker tho, its not properly showing

Comment: so there would be a common class which will be shown in both active and inactive mode? and another class that will change when state changes? in that case: put the common class in class="common-class" and ng-class="{'active-class': isActive,'in-active-class':!isActive}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a toggle on `ng-click` then just change the `ng-class` by this.

```
ng-class="{'mode': isActive, 'classThatIsSupposedToBeShownOnInActive': !isActive}"
```

Then it should display the class you want on load and show `mode` class on `ng-click`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks It worked! but how about when I click a different span? the class should go back to the original state

Comment: You just have to toggle the `$scope.isActive` boolean to false on another span click. :)

Comment: Try this `<span ng-click="anotherSpanClick()" id="differentSpan">Different Span Content</span>` 
`$scope.anotherSpanClick = function(){$scope.isActive = false;}`

Comment: hi again @mJunaidSalaat can I ask again for your help?

Comment: I have another problem that seems to be the same as this one but my problem now is how can I change the class of a certain button upon selecting a certain radiobutton? @mJunaidSalaat

Comment: You can do it in the `ng-change` event in angularjs. the method will be same here just instead of `ng-click` use `ng-change`. More [details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077320/angularjs-trigger-when-radio-button-is-selected)